# How to delete the space between UITableViewCell in plain style UITableView on visionOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, visionos

[image]

The picture above is the effect of the following sample code after running on visionOS. Below is the full sample code:

```swift
final class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let _view = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        _view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        _view.backgroundColor = .red
        _view.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        _view.delegate = self
        _view.dataSource = self
        return _view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 24.3
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
}
```

As can be seen from the screenshot, there is a certain spacing between Cells (blue), and the TableView (red) is not filled on the left and right.

I searched for relevant information but found nothing that could help me. **Does anyone know how to remove the spacing between Cells?** Looking forward to getting help, my sincerest gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

[edit: now I have]. I haven’t tested this.

Since we’re in UIKit land (even though we’re on visionOS), the simplest way I can think of to achieve what you’ve observed would be if visionOS has changed the UITableView default `.separatorColor` to transparent.

Try `tableView.separatorColor = .yellow` to see if that’s what is going on. Then `tableView.separatorColor = .blue` to make it look like the cells are continuous with no space between.

Comment: I also doubted whether this was a larger dividing line, but unfortunately `separatorColor = .yellow` has no effect.

Comment: I tested this morning, and was able to change the separator color. I don't have your exact setup, am probably adding the tableview slightly differently. Also try `.none` for `UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle`? I'm building an iPad app and running on Vision Pro Simulator.

Comment: After `_view.dataSource = self` I wrote `_view.separatorColor = .yellow`, the rest of the code remained the same as in the example, and finally I ran it on the vision pro simulator (1.1), but it had no effect. Can you tell me where you set `separatorColor`?